# Can I use imported functions and classes globally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I want to switch from all classes in the html header file to the module approach.

I want to use some methods and function on buttons and other elements.

In my index.html in the head section:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

Inside the main.js:

```
import {writeAlert} from './test.js';
```

Inside the test.js:

```
export function writeAlert () {
    alert('I am an alert');
}
```

Inside the body element of the index.html

```
<button onlick="writeAlert()">Alert</button>
```

I am getting the error message that the function (or in other cases class) is not defined. So what is the way to implement a global use of imported functions? Is the client actually able to see my whole source code with that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a patchy answer. But, the same idea can be extended further.

In main.js:

```
import {writeAlert} from './test.js';
window.writeAlert = writeAlert;
```

After that, “writeAlert” is accessible from HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers imported in a module are not visible on the outside.

Two solutions, in order of personal preference:

1. Move the callback installation from HTML to JS:

   - Change the button definition to: `<button id="alertButton">Alert</button>`
   - Add the following code to `main.js`, or another module that imports `writeAlert`:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     document.getElementById("alertButton").onclick = writeAlert;
   });
   ```
2. "Export" `writeAlert` onto `window` in one of the modules:

   ```
   import { writeAlert } from "./test.js";
   window.writeAlert = writeAlert;
   ```

   In this way, `writeAlert` is accessible anywhere in your code, HTML or JS, without any imports. But this rather defeats the purpose of using imports in the first place and isn't as elegant.